# How do I get the filename from inotifywait events?

Tags: command-line, scripts, inotify

So I'm doing a simple `inotifywait` loop to watch for changes in a Bootstrap directory:

```
while inotifywait -r -q --format %w bootstrap/; do
    echo "something happened"
    [[ $filename == *.js ]] && uglifyjs .....
    [[ $filename == *.less ]] && lessc bootstrap.less
done
```

You don't really need to worry about the internals but I just can't get the filename back into a bash scope. `inotifywait` echos out the filename (with help from the format argument) but how do I capture that and use it later on (in my case, as `$filename`)?

---

If you want a simple, short test harness:

```
touch testfile
while inotifywait testfile do; echo "..."; done
```

And then you can just run `touch testfile` when you want to trigger it.

Comment: Stopping by in 2016, but the answer seems to be `--format "%w%f", since `%w` yields the directory of the file and `%f` the base filename. Not sure how this handles symlinks or the like.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The cleaner way is illustrated in [this blog entry](http://xaroumenosloukoumas.wordpress.com/2011/01/28/watching-directories-for-file-changes-with-inotifywait/):

```
inotifywait -m -r -q --format '%w' bootstrap/ | while read FILE
do
  echo "something happened on path $FILE"
done
```

Comment: Format probably needs to be '%f' instead of '%w' to get filename

Comment: And to get path+filename --format '%w%f', that is a usable path : ' )

Comment: Can we prevent the double outputs?

Comment: @eigenfield to prevent double outputs, add `-e create` or whatever event you want to filter on. I think duplicate outputs are happening because create/open/close events are happening all at once.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I just needed to restructure the `while` so that I captured the output of `inotifywait`:

```
while true; do
    echo "something happened"
    filename=$(inotifywait -r -q --format %w bootstrap/)
    [[ $filename == *.js ]] && uglifyjs .....
    [[ $filename == *.less ]] && lessc bootstrap.less
done
```

I'm still curious to know if there are cleaner ways of doing this.

Comment: The answer by @abergmeier is continuous so you won't miss events that occur while you are processing eg: uglifyjs or lessc etc.