# is it possible to change the trashcan to use the shred function?

Tags: xubuntu, delete, trash, permanent-delete, shredding

I know that the trashcan on Ubunutu Mate desktop performs a simple delete process, where one could theoretically recover the files after deletion.
Is there an option to change that default functionality, and opt for using shred, or a shred like command to permanently delete files?

Comment: Do you want to shred files on emptying the trashcan, or do you want to shred files instead of putting them into trash?

Comment: Shred when emptying seems preferable.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve this would probably be to watch the trash location (`~/.local/share/Trash/Files` I believe) for files, and use inotifywait to shred files when they arrive. `inotifywait` can be installed with `sudo apt-get install inotify-tools`

```
inotifywait -m ~/.local/share/Trash/Files -e moved_to -rq --format '%w%f' |
while read file; do
    shred $file
done
```

This snippet will shred any files as they appear in the trash folder. In addition you can use `gvfs-trash --empty` to empty the trash once the shred is complete, or you can ask `shred` to remove the file after overwriting, with `shred -u`.

(This answer was largely based on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24952/script-to-monitor-folder-for-new-files and [How do I get the filename from inotifywait events?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385333/how-do-i-get-the-filename-from-inotifywait-events) which may provide some additional information)